# What is error in code of view did load so it crashed progrme?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am using this code for view did load..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
myPicker.hidden=TRUE;
NSArray * shopping=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lie in bed",
                    @"Shower",
                    @"Brush Teeth",
                    @"Eat",
                    @"Make Lunch",
                    @"Dressed",
                    @"Make up",
                    @"Hair",
                    @"Prepare Childern",
                    @"Other",nil];

for(int i=0;i<61;i++)
{
    if (array_time ==nil) {
        array_time=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Min",i];
    [array_time addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
    [str release]; 
}
for (int i=0; i<61; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[array_time objectAtIndex:i]);
}

if(array_from==nil)
{
    array_from=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[array_from addObject:shopping];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

after that i have coded for table view. I have checked by applying break point all over but i was terminate after view did load. On console it is not giving any error.
So what is mistake in this code or any where?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: By terminating do you mean the app is exiting or there's just a black screen and nothing happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't really need to release this string:

str

```
  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Min",i];
    [array_time addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]];
    [str release];
```

you didn't allocate it